# Entity Framework : Put FK in the Principle table

Tags: entity-framework

I used the following code to configure cascade delete for two entity `Entity1` (Principle) and `Entity2` (Dependent)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>()
                    .HasRequired(x => x.Entity2)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal()
                    .Map(x => x.MapKey("Entity1_Id"))
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This causes FK that represent the relation between the two entities to be in the `Entity2` table, is it possible to change this to make FK in the `Entity1` table while keeping the `Entity1` as Principle and `Entity2` as Dependent?

Comment: are you trying to make one to one relation  ???

Comment: Yes of course, otherwise it will be non sense.

Comment: In EF one to one relation, always the dependent entity will have a FK of Principle table. the other way is not possible.

Comment: Then `Entity2` isn't dependent any more. It can exist on its own.

Answer (score 0):

For 1-to-1 relationships, the PK would normally be the same name in both tables. Having a secondary ID in the primary table forms a many-to-1 relationship. For 1-to-0/1 you'd be looking at:
I.e.

```
public class MyEntity
{
   public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
   // ...
}

public class RelatedEntity
{
  public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
  // ...
}
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                    .HasRequired(x => x.RelatedEntity)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal() // 1-1 in EF, 1-0/1 in SQL Server
                    .Map(x => x.MapKey("EntityId"))
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

If the RelatedEntity has a reference back to the MyEntity then you shouldn't need to use MapKey:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                    .HasRequired(x => x.RelatedEntity)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.MyEntity)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Otherwise you are looking at a ManyToOne relationship (like selecting a lookup) which would have the related ID in the primary table but no relation back to the parent:

```
public class MyEntity
{
  public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
  public virtual RelatedEntity RelatedEntity { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
  .HasRequired(x => x.RelatedEntity)
  .WithMany()
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

By enabling cascade delete this would allow it to mimic a 1-1 relationship, however structurally it's many to 1, meaning there is nothing schema-side or in EF to stop you assigning the same related entity to 2 different primary records. If you do that, you will get an error when you try to delete one of the primaries if Cascade delete is True.

*edit* The cascade option on the many-to-1 scenario above will not cascade from Parent to Child, but it does cascade from child to parent in that case. If you have a DbSet of Entity1, but no DbSet of Entity2 available then you can temporarily add a DbSet of Entity2 to remove the child and associated parent:

where "context" is your instance of the DbContext

```
var entity2Set = context.Set<Entity2>();
entity2Set.Remove(entity1.Entity2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This will remove both the Entity1 and Entity2 when CascadeDelete is True.

As said, it mimics a 1-to-1 allowing the Entity1 to hold the Entity2Id, but not recommended since there is nothing stopping you in EF or SQL from assigning the same Entity2Id to multiple Entity1 records. (The cascade in that case would delete multiple Entity1 records)  For proper 1-to-1, use the same ID on both the parent and child entity.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get how this solves my problem, could you please explain more.

Comment: If you want Entity2 to have it's own ID and reference that ID in the parent entity, that is a many-to-1 relationship, not 1-to-1. For 1-to-1 you use the same PK in both tables.  I just tried the cascadeDelete on the many-to-1 scenario and that doesn't work, it leaves the child orphaned. The cascade goes from child to parent in that case. (Deleting Entity1 does not remove Entity2, but deleting Entity2 will cascade delete Entity1) I'll update my answer to clarify that.